# Get text values from HBox

Tags: javafx, scalafx

Say I have an HBox like this:

```
val texts = new HBox {
  content = Seq(new TextArea, new TextArea)
}
```

Now I'd like to get `TextArea`s' text values in a collection. How can I get to these `TextArea`s? `texts.content` is an `ObservableList[javafx.scene.Node]`, not `ObservableList[TextArea]`.

I've tried type casting like this:

```
texts.content.get(0).asInstanceOf[TextArea].getText
```

And gott the following exception: `java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.control.TextArea cannot be cast to scalafx.scene.control.TextArea`

Comment: How about `TypeCasting` ?

Comment: I've tried `texts.content(0).asInstanceOf[TextArea]` and `texts.content(0) match { case te: TextArea => ...` and both resulted in exceptions.

Comment: with match I've got not an exception but warning `fruitless type test: a value of type javafx.scene.Node cannot also be a scalafx.scene.control.TextArea`

Comment: `scalafx.scene.control.TextArea` ??

Comment: @ItachiUchiha yes, what's wrong with that?

Comment: Don't you think, it should be `javafx.scene.control.TextArea` ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha oh thanks, it does work after I've changed the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type cast the elements while fetching them, for example:

```
TextArea txt1 = (TextArea)observableList.get(0);
TextArea txt2 = (TextArea)observableList.get(1);
```

Or, if you have multiple `TextArea`

```
for(Node node: observableList){
   TextArea txt = (TextArea)node;
   //Do something with the txtArea
}
```